# How to restart data() on route with no params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a problem to force a restart on new route

I have an route

`/editor` but also `/editor?_id=dasd448846acsca`

`/editor` is simple component with form with empty inputs
`/editor?_id=dasd448846acsca` this component is the same as /editor but just with filled inputs from DB
I want to be able to open `/editor` component (using some function, link) with empty inputs from component `/editor?_id=dasd448846acsca`

I used `this.$router.push('editor'); this.$forceUpdate();` in function and route is changed, but data in restarted (inputs are not empty)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the `data()` with initial values when I change my path